# How to extract paragraphs separated by a comma?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

This is a piece of code from which I am trying to obtain data.

```
<p>ul. Niecała 10</p>
<p>05-800 Pruszków</p>

</div>
```

I did it this way:

```
address = result.find('div', attrs={'class': 'section address'}).get_text()
```

Unfortunately, the result does not satisfy me. The texts from the paragraphs are stuck together. I would like these paragraphs to be separated by a comma.

Now:

```
ul. Niecała 1005-800 Pruszków
```

I would like it to be:

```
ul. Niecała 10, 05-800 Pruszków
```

How do I do that? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) generator and join by `', '` (if you want a string), example:

```
address = ', '.join(result.find('div', class_='section address').stripped_strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an even easier way than `.stripped_strings` - just use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) directly with a comma as a `separator`:

```
address = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'section address'})
print(address.get_text(", ", strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
ul. Niecała 10, 05-800 Pruszków
```